# RABL - attributes within child node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rabl

If I create a child node in RABL using the node() method, how can I control the attributes that are presented?

The JSON output is this:

```
[
    {
        "location": {
            "latitude": 33333,
            "longitude": 44444,
            "address": "xxxxxxx",
            "title": "yyyy",
            "url": "http://www.google.com",
            "rate": {
                "created_at": "2012-09-02T11:13:13Z",
                "id": 1,
                "location_id": 1,
                "pair": "zzzzzz",
                "updated_at": "2012-09-02T12:55:28Z",
                "value": 1.5643
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want to get rid of the created_at, updated_at and location_id attributes.

I have this in my view file:

```
collection @locations
attributes :latitude, :longitude, :address, :title, :url
node (:rate) do   
  |location| location.rates.where(:pair => @pair).first
end
```

I tried using a partial and the 'extend' method, but it totally screwed things up. Also, I tried adding attributes to the block but it didn't work (the output was as specified in the attributes but it didn't show the values for each attribute).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code: `location.rates.where(:pair => @pair).first` returns the whole Rate object. If you want specific fields (for example: all, except for create_at, updated_at, etc.) then you have two options:

**Manually** describe the hash in node():

```
node (:rate) do |location|  
   loc = location.rates.where(:pair => @pair).first
   { :pair => loc.pair, :value => loc.value, etc... }
end
```

Or you can do **this**:

```
node (:rate) do |location|  
   location.rates.where(:pair => @pair).select('pair, value, etc...').first
end
```

...and as a side note, I should say that placing logic (rates.where) in your view is not a best practice. see if your controller can do that for the view using the Rate model.

Comment: Thanks... I went with the 'manual' solution in the end. The reason for doing this logic in the view, is that i have to go through each Location object and look up the rate, then output both. I tried to think of doing this in the controller, but it just seemed too complex (I guess it would involve creating some new objects to hold each Location and corresponding Rates) .. so I decided for simplicity to do it in the view

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't be able to use `attributes` within the node block, since "self" in there is still  the root object or collection, so in your case `@locations`. See also [RABL wiki: Tips and tricks (When to use Child and Node)](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Tips-and-tricks)

In the node block you could simply create your custom response by only listing the attributes that your interested in:

```
node :rate do |location|
  rate = location.rates.where(:pair => @pair).first
  {:id => rate.id, :location_id => rate.location_id, :value => rate.value}
end
```

You can also try the approach using a partial:

In `app/views/rates/show.json.rabl`

```
object @rate
attributes :id, :location_id, :value
```

Then in your @locations rabl view:

```
node :rate do |location|
  rate = location.rates.where(:pair => @pair).first
  partial("rates/show", :object => rate)
end
```

Comment: Really? The same approach works for me. What is the error you're getting?